# Authentication issue Node.js with passport and Nginx as proxy server

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, nginx, passport.js

I'm running a Node application that uses Passport.js for authentication on port 3000.
Nginx is used as a proxy server to listen on port 80 and proxy pass the requests to port 3000. 
Passport.js is used for authentication of the users.

Authentication protocol is as follows:
The user requests example.com and is redirected to example.com/login if he is not logged in.
After a successful login the user is redirected again to example.com.

- The issue occurs when I'm trying to log in using Safari 6 on the Ipad and in Internet Explorer 9 (suspected as a customer has the same issue).
  What happens is that the application redirects to example.com/login instead of example.com/ when using the correct credentials.
- The problem does not occur in Chrome 40 for example.
- The problem does not occur when nginx is avoided by using example.com:3000 in Safari.
- To make it worse: sometimes it does work for no apparent reason.

I suspect it has something to do with Nginx and the order in which files are requested.

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

Part of application code:

```
app.post('/api/login', function (req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate('local-login', function (err, user, info) {
  if (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(401).send(info);
  }
  req.logIn(user, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    return res.send({
      username: user.username
    });
  });
})(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/views/index.html');
});


function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.redirect('/login');
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

I'm wondering whether someone can help me with this.
I'm happy to provide extra code or explanation where required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nginx turned out to have nothing to do with with.
By directly accessing using example.com:3000 the problem occurred occasionally as well.

I noticed that at one point the browser said I was visiting example.com and was displaying example.com/login. 
I could not find any evidence of it on the internet, but I suspect that Safari/IE9 cache the redirected page and link it to the original URL. 
So here is the story line of what happens next.

1. User browses to example.com/
2. Gets redirected to example.com/login (Browser caches example.com/ but saves the login page)
3. User logs in and gets redirected to example.com/
4. Browser has / in cache and loads the login page.
5. Unexplainable bug and headaches for the developer.

'Solved' by adding middleware that adds no cache headers when / is requested.

```
app.get('/', isLoggedIn, noCache, function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/views/index.html');
});

function noCache(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  res.header('Expires', '-1');
  res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
  next();
}
```

Comment: +1 fixed a caching issue for me on Internet Explorer that no other fixes helped, much appreciated that you shared your solution.